# jq convert comma separated JSON objects into array

Tags: json, object, jq

I have files which have N JSON objects and they are separated by comma (,)

```
{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3},{"d":2},{"e":1},{"f":2} ...
```

I would like to convert them into one JSON array with N objects using `jq`

```
[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3},{"d":2},{"e":1},{"f":2} ...]
```

I tried `jq -R 'split(",")' myfile.json` but it gives me an array of N strings

```
[
  "{\"a\":1}",
  "{\"b\":2}",
  "{\"a\":1}",
  "{\"b\":2}",
  "{\"a\":1}",
  "{\"b\":2}",
  "{\"a\":1}",
  "{\"b\":2}" ....
]
```

Any idea?

Comment: It's probably easiest to just wrap your input in [.....]

Comment: My file contains millions of json object, maybe it's not an efficient way to        read whole file ?

Comment: Please clarify whether any of the JSON objects might contain more than one key, and whether any of the key names or values might contain a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, you just need to map `fromjson` to the array, e.g.:

```
jq -Rc 'split(",") | map(fromjson)' myfile.json
```

Output:

```json
[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3},{"d":2},{"e":1},{"f":2}]
```

However, if you are dealing with huge inputs, perhaps use a more streamable command to split the input into chunks, e.g. with `tr`:

```
<myfile.json tr ',' '\n' | jq -c .
```

Output:

```json
{"a":1}
{"b":2}
{"c":3}
{"d":2}
{"e":1}
{"f":2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have millions of these JSON objects, let me first suggest an efficient way to produce a stream of them in the JSON-Lines format (i.e., with "newline" as the delimiter).

WARNING: THE FOLLOWING ASSUMES THAT THE OBJECTS DO NOT CONTAIN JSON STRINGS WITH COMMAS.

Let's assume the comma-separated objects are in a file named objects.txt.
First, create a file, program.jq, with the following jq program:

```
def one:
  (try input catch null)
  | if . == 0 then empty elif . == null then one else (., one) end;

one
```

Then assuming your shell allows it, the invocation:

```
 (cat objects.txt; echo 0) |
   sed $'s/,/,\\\n/g' | 
   jq -n -c -f program.jq objects.txt
```

will produce the stream, one JSON object per line. This is a very manageable format. For example, to produce an array, you could pipe the above-mentioned stream into `jq -s .`

However, if the goal is solely to produce a JSON array, then as pointed out elsewhere, the most efficient approach would be to enclose the comma-separated objects in square brackets, along the lines of:

```
(echo "["; cat objects.txt; echo "]")
```

So the relevant question here, perhaps, is: what's the real goal?  It seems doubtful that having an unmanageably large array of small JSON objects is likely to more useful than either the original comma-separated sequence, or a simple stream.